# Resmo git-ftp has egrep error with Mountain Lion

Tags: git, ftp, installation, grep, git-ftp

I have a problem with git-ftp "resmo" script. It worked fine before the 10.8.2 osx update.

First I installed it in this way

```
$ git clone https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp.git
$ cd git-ftp
$ git checkout master
$ sudo make install
```

after I saw on the resmo git-page that this issue is common and he suggests to install it from the develop branch. So I uninstalled it with:
$ sudo make uninstall

and after re-installed it in this way

```
$ git checkout develop
$ sudo make install
```

but when I do "git ftp push"...

```
egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid
No changed files for ftp.mydomain.com. Everything up-to-date.
```

But it's not true because I have make a code update and commited it

what can I do?
Did someone solve it?

My versions:

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion 
10.8.2
$ git ftp --version
git-ftp version 0.8.3-snapshot
$ egrep --version
egrep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Comment: Try filing an [issue @Github](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/issues/163 for a lengthy discussion about this problem, it seems either upgrading to a newer git-ftp or installing a different version of egrep as mentioned [here](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/issues/163#issuecomment-15831830) and [here](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/issues/163#issuecomment-15955031) will solve the problem.